# JavaScript function execution time

Tags: javascript

I wanted to test the execution time of console.log, but whatever number I set as the delay for setTimeout, it is still executed after console.log. I don't understand why so.

```js
function first() {
    console.log("This should be printed first");
}

setTimeout(first, 0.00001);

console.log("This should be printed second");
```

Comment: How would `setTimeout` help you learn about the execution time of `console.log`? And why do you want to do this anyway? What do you want to do with this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout):

> **delay** Optional 
>  The time, in milliseconds that the timer should wait before the specified function or code is executed. If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning execute "immediately", or more accurately, the next event cycle. Note that in either case, the actual delay may be longer than intended; see Reasons for delays longer than specified below.

No matter how small the delay, the `first` function is going to be put on a queue and not looked at until the current event cycle (which is in the middle of running the current function) has finished (which won't be until after the last `console.log` statement has been executed).

**Further reading**:

- [Concurrency model and the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
- [JavaScript Event Loop](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-event-loop/)